# Partial specialization for destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am just working on my school homework, and I am interested if C++ could create specialized destructor for pointers. I know that this is not good practice, but because of performance, I want to do it this way. Also because I am curious about it. So lets say, that we have this class:

```
template<typename T,int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
class BinomialHeapLite
{
private:
    class Node
    {
        Node* next;
        T instance;
    }
    Node* top;
public:
    ~BinomialHeapLite();
}
```

Now I want destructor, that delete just node, if is T only type and delete also inner instance, if is T pointer..

```
template<typename T, int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
BinomialHeapLite<T,comp>::~BinomialHeapLite()
{
    //some code
    delete this->top;
}

template<typename T, int(*comp)(const T* &first, const T* &second)>
BinomialHeapLite<T*,comp>::~BinomialHeapLite()
{
    //some code
    delete this->top->instance;
    delete this->top;
}
```

But this give me "invalid use of incomplete type". I also want to use pure C++11, because I want to be independent to another libraries (also standards libraries), moreover that libraries are not permitted in out system.
Is something like this possible in pure C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving your `BinomialHeapLite` class a responsibility that **it shouldn't have**: cleaning up `instance` if it's a heap-allocated pointer.

That burden should be **on the user of your class**: what if he is already calling `delete` in its own code? What if the object is supposed to be reused after your `BinomialHeapLite` is destroyed?

All your class should do is provide a generic container that **manages its own** memory. For that task, your should also use **smart pointers** *([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in this case*):

```
template<typename T,int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
class BinomialHeapLite
{
private:
    class Node
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
        T instance;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Node> top;
}
```

You won't need an hand-written destructor then. Refer to the ["rule of three/five/zero"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more information.

---

If you really want to implement your flawed/unconventional design, you could use a partially specialized helper struct that calls `delete` if its type is a pointer:

```
template <typename T>
struct dtor_helper
{
    static void do_it(T&&){}
};

template <typename T>
struct dtor_helper<T*>
{
    static void do_it(T* x){ delete x; }
};

template<typename T, int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
BinomialHeapLite<T,comp>::~BinomialHeapLite()
{
    //some code
    dtor_helper<T>::do_it(this->top->instance);
    delete this->top;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JZqmvDWSQ3FOKOxl)

Comment: As I said, I dont want to use external libraries (smart pointers included). I use that class, so I know that I will not use that memory later and that I didnt delete that memory before destructor call. Because it is heap, I cannot pop each element and delete it, because its performance expensive. And mainly, I am currious, if is this possible in pure C++.

Comment: @PatrikValkovič: Smart pointers are part of the C++11 standard library. Why wouldn't you want to use the standard library? `std::unique_ptr` incurs no overhead compared to raw `new/delete` for unique ownership semantics. What you are trying to do is possible in "pure" C++ - I'll update my answer. But your design is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Because not all parts of standard library are available in our testing system. I know that smart pointers have no overhead, but there are not permitted. I am dealing with it mainly because of performance, because popping each element and deleting it (how it should looks like) have O(3 * log(n!)) whereas this approach have O(n). But thanks, second example works fine.

Comment: @pat If you cannot use `std` smart pointers, then write your own smart pointer.  There is zero good reason to make your type both be a smart pointer and whatever binomial thing you are writing.  Doing so is ridiculously error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not partially specialize a member function. But you can partially specialize a class template:

```
template <class T>
struct Deallocator{
  template <class Node>
  static void Deallocate(const Node &node){}
};

template <class T>
struct Deallocator<T *>{
  template <class Node>
  static void Deallocate(const Node &node){}
};

template<typename T, int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
BinomialHeapLite<T,comp>::~BinomialHeapLite()
{
    //some code
    Deallocator<T>::Deallocate(top);
}
```

Or overload a function :

```
template<typename T,int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
class BinomialHeapLite
{
private:
    struct Node // a little change here
    {
        Node* next;
        T instance;
    };
    Node* top;

    template <class Ty>
    void deallocate(Ty *) {}
    template <class Ty>
    void deallocate(Ty &) {}
public:
    ~BinomialHeapLite();
};

template<typename T, int(*comp)(const T& first, const T& second)>
BinomialHeapLite<T,comp>::~BinomialHeapLite()
{
    //some code
    deallocate(top->instance);
}
```